# Titanium webview leaflet/gmaps pinch-zoom not working properly

Tags: google-maps, webview, titanium, leaflet, pinchzoom

I am developing a Titanium webview mobile application using a local HTML file (not remote) for Android. My HTML code contains a map (similar to Google Maps) and allows users to use a zoom gesture.

In order to enable zooming and scaling in my local HTML web page (not just on the map), Im adding following meta tag in my HTML header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
          maximum-scale=1.01, user-scalable=1">
```

The minimum value of the `maximum-scale` property is 1.01
Aside from that, my `ApplicationWindows.js` file sets the webview's `scalesPageToFit` property to `true` as follows:

```
var webView = Ti.UI.createWebView({        
        url : "/HTML/index.html",
        scalesPageToFit : true
});
```

These two changes enable the pinch-zoom feature in my application. However, *the pinch-zoom feature only works on the map if the user has previously pinch-zoomed somewhere* (in any other part of the DOM, but outside the map). So, as an example, let's suppose that this is my HTML code (basic gmaps example):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" 
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
       maximum-scale=2, user-scalable=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 70%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script>
    var map;
    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8, center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(
          document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);     
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notice that the map only fills 70% of the screen, there is an 30% 'blank' space at the bottom.

My ApplicationWindow.js file is:

```
// Application Window Component Constructor
function ApplicationWindow() {          
    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor : '#FFFFFF',
        modal : true,
        exitOnClose : true  // Android only
    });
    var webView = Ti.UI.createWebView({        
        url : '/HTML/gmap.html',
        scalesPageToFit: true
    }); 
    self.add(webView);  
    return self;
}

//make constructor function the public component interface
module.exports = ApplicationWindow;
```

Running the app (in either the Android emulator, Android mobile or Android tablet) the behaviour is always the same: *Pinch-zoom on the map only works if we have previously zoomed any other part of the DOM* (in this case, in the white space at the bottom). Once zoom is detected, pinch zoom gesture works also on the map but not before!

Details:

- Titanium SDK: 3.1.2GA -
- Platform & version: Tested on Android v.2.3.4, v.4.0, v.4.0.3
- Device: Emulator, mobile and tablet
- Host OS: Tested on Ubuntu and Debian
- Titanium Studio: 3.1.3.201309132423

I am not sure if I am doing something incorrectly or this is just a Titanium bug... Thanks in advance!